# How to make PHP Pagination is working in Mobile?

Tags: php, css, mobile, responsive-design, pagination

I have implement pagination in PHP. 
It's works fine on Desktop and Laptop but but its not working on mobile devices.

`member_list.php`

```
<?php
include "../connection.php";
extract($_REQUEST);

$perPage = 50; // total records per page
// page
$conditionArr = array(); // array for condition
$condition = ""; // conditions
$pages = ""; // how many pages created
$type = "";
$company = "";
$message = "";
$rersArr = array();
$data = array();
$templeArr = array();

if ($sabhasadnumber != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "sabhasad_number = '" . $sabhasadnumber . "'");
}

if ($Sakhe != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "sakhe_id = '" . $Sakhe . "'");
}

if ($g != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "gender LIKE '%" . $g . "%'");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE village_id = '$id' and is_active = '1' and status = '1' ";



if (sizeOf($conditionArr) > 0) {
    $condition = implode(" AND ", $conditionArr);
//    echo $condition;
    $sql .= " AND $condition";
}

$start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
$pages = ceil($count / $perPage);
$sql .= " ORDER BY members_id ASC";
$sql .= " limit $start,$perPage ";
$num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);


?>
<input type="hidden" name="total_page" id="total_page" value="<?php echo $pages; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_page" class="current_page" id="current_page"
                   value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
    <div class="member--items">
                                <div class="row gutter--15 AdjustRow">

                                    <div class="row">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>


   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12" style="height:300px">

                                                <div class="member--item ">

                                                    <?php
                                                    $imgurl = "";
                                                    if ($row["image"] != "") {
                                                        $imgurl = "../admin/uploads/" . $row["image"];
                                                    } else {
                                                        $imgurl = "../admin/uploads/default_profile.jpg";
                                                    }

                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="img img-circle">
                                                        <a href="sabhasad_family.php?id=<?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?>" class="btn-link">
                                                            <img src="<?php echo $imgurl; ?>" alt=""
                                                                 style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">

<!--                                                                  <img src="../admin/uploads/default_profile.jpg" alt=""-->
<!--                                                                 style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">-->
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="name">
                                                        <h3 class="h fs--12">
                                                            <p>
                                                                <a href="sabhasad_family.php?id=<?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['surname'] ." " ;

                                                                    echo $row['name'] ." ";

                                                                    echo $row['middle_name'] ." "; ?></a></p>

                                                        </h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="activity">
                                                        <p>સભાસદ નંબર : <?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?> </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>





    <?php
}
}


else { ?>

    <?php
}

?>
```

`member_list.js`

```
var page = 1;
var total_page = "";

function getresult(searches) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "process/member_list.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            sabhasadnumber: $("#sabhasadnumber").val(),
            id: $("#village_id").val(),
            Sakhe: $("#Sakhe").val(),
            g: $("#g").val(),

            page: page
        },

        success: function (data) {

        //  alert(data);



            if (data != "") {
                if (searches === true) {
                    $("#mlist").html(data);
                } else {


                    $("#mlist").append(data);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    getresult(false);

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            if (parseInt($(".current_page:last").val()) < parseInt($("#total_page").val())) {
                page = parseInt($(".current_page:last").val()) + 1;
                //  alert("scrool"+$(".current_page:last").val());
                getresult(false);
            }
        }
    });


    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $("#Sakhe").val("");

        $("#sabhasadnumber").val("");
        $("#g").val("");


        page = 1;
        getresult(true);
    });


    $("#shopsubmit").click(function () {
        page = 1;
        getresult(true);
    });

    $("#freset").click(function () {
        $("#subcategory").val("");


        page = 1;
        getresult(true);
    });


});
```

My front page code look like this

`village.php`

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
include 'header.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];

$totalvillagemember = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "select members_id from members WHERE village_id = $id AND is_active = '1' and status = '1' "));
$villagename = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name from village WHERE village_id = $id");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($villagename);

?>

<body>

<!-- Preloader Start -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div class="preloader--inner"></div>
</div>
<!-- Preloader End -->

<!-- Wrapper Start -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Header Section Start -->

    <!-- Header Section End -->

    <!-- Page Header Start -->
    <div class="page--header pt--60 pb--60 text-center" data-bg-img="img/page-header-img/bg.jpg" data-overlay="0.85">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h2 class="h1 text-white">સભ્યો</h2>
            </div>

            <ul class="breadcrumb text-gray ff--primary">
                <li><a href="home-1.html" class="btn-link">હોમ</a></li>
                <li class="active"><span class="text-primary">સભ્યો</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page Header End -->

    <!-- Page Wrapper Start -->
    <section class="page--wrapper pt--80 pb--20">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Main Content Start -->

                <div class="main--content col-md-8 pb--60" data-trigger="stickyScroll">
                    <div class="main--content-inner">
                        <!-- Filter Nav Start -->

                        <div class="filter--nav clearfix">
                            <div class="filter--link">
                                <h2 class="">ગામ : <?php echo $row1['name']; ?></h2>
                                <h2 class="">કુલ સભ્ય :<?php echo number_format($totalvillagemember) ?></h2>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <div id="mlist" name="mlist">
                        </div>


                        <!-- Page Count End -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Content End -->



                <!-- Main Sidebar Start -->
                <div class="main--sidebar col-md-4 pb--60" data-trigger="stickyScroll">
                    <!-- Widget Start -->
                    <div class="widget">
                        <h2 class="h4 fw--700 widget--title">સભ્ય શોધો</h2>

                        <!-- Buddy Finder Widget Start -->
                        <div class="buddy-finder--widget">
                            <form name="village" id="village">
                                <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">શોધી રહ્યો છુ</span>

                                                <select class="form-control form-sm" name="g" id="g">
                                                    <option value=""> પસંદ કરો
                                                    </option>

                                                       <option value = "M">પુરુષ</option>
                                                       <option value = "F">સ્ત્રી</option>


                                                </select>






                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">સભાસદ નંબર</span>

                                                <input type="text" name="sabhasadnumber" id="sabhasadnumber"
                                                       class="form-control form-sm"
                                                       placeholder="સભાસદ નંબર">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="hidden" id="village_id" name="village_id"
                                                       value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                                <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">સાખે</span>

                                                <select class="form-control form-sm" name="Sakhe" id="Sakhe">
                                                    <option value=""> સાખે પસંદ કરો
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from sakhe where status = 1 order by sakhe_id asc");
                                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                                        echo "<option value = " . $row['sakhe_id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-xs-12">


                                        <button type="button" onclick="getresult()" class="btn btn-primary" id="shopsubmit" name="shopsubmit">
                                            સબમિટ કરો
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" onclick="getresult()" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                id="reset" name="reset">
                                            ફરીથી સેટ કરો
                                        </button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <!-- Widget End -->
                </div>
                <!-- Main Sidebar End -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page Wrapper End -->

    <!-- Footer Section Start -->

    <!-- Footer Widgets End -->

    <!-- Footer Extra Start -->
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
    <!-- Footer Section End -->
</div>
<!-- Wrapper End -->

<!-- Back To Top Button Start -->
<div id="backToTop">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- Back To Top Button End -->





<!-- ==== Plugins Bundle ==== -->
<script src="js/plugins.min.js"></script>

<!-- ==== Color Switcher Plugin ==== -->

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<!-- ==== Main Script ==== -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>-->
<script src="myjs/member_list.js"></script>
</body>

<!-- Mirrored from themelooks.us/demo/socifly/html/members.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 30 Sep 2019 09:33:46 GMT -->
</html>
```

This pagination is not working only on Mobile devices.
Please help.

Comment: Your PHP code runs in the server not in the client and your provided code doesn't generate different results for Desktop and mobile devices. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I have added front page `villlage.php` is there any issue with this file ?? @AliKhalili

Comment: Hi !! I am using this `$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() -500 ) {
           

            if (parseInt($(".current_page:last").val()) < parseInt($("#total_page").val())) {
                page = parseInt($(".current_page:last").val()) + 1;
                 alert("scrool"+$(".current_page:last").val());
                getresult(false);
            }  }
    }); `  It is working for mobile. But it repeat some record. Is there any solution for dublication. @AliKhalili

Comment: @MeetPatel Most probably, the function is called more than once so you add the next page and in the meanwhile (before finishing the getresult), you are calling the function again! You can use some flag to solve this problem